# comparing large vectors in python

Tags: python, vector

I have two large vectors (~133000 values) of different length. They are each sortet from small to large values. I want to find values that are similar within a given tolerance. This is my solution but it is very slow. Is there a way to speed this up?

```
import numpy as np

for lv in range(np.size(vector1)):
    for lv_2 in range(np.size(vector2)):
        if np.abs(vector1[lv_2]-vector2[lv])<.02: 
            print(vector1[lv_2],vector2[lv],lv,lv_2)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is far from optimal. You compare way too much values. Assume you are at a certain position in `vector1` and the current value in `vector2` is already more than `0.02` bigger. Why would you compare the rest of `vector2`?

Start with something like

```
pos1 = 0
pos2 = 0
```

Now compare the values at those postions in your vectors. If the difference is too big, move the position of the smaller one fowared and check again. Continue until you reach the end of one vector.

Answer (score 0):

haven't tested it, but the following should work. The idea is to exploit the fact that the vectors are sorted

```
lv_1, lv_2 = 0,0
while lv_1 < len(vector1) and lv_2 < len(vector2):
  if np.abs(vector1[lv_2]-vector2[lv_1])<.02:
     print(vector1[lv_2],vector2[lv_1],lv_1,lv_2)
     lv_1 += 1
     lv_2 += 1
  elif vector1[lv_1] < vector2[lv_2]: lv_1 += 1
  else: lv_2 += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code gives a nice increase in performance that depends upon how dense the numbers are. Using a set of 1000 random numbers, sampled uniformly between 0 and 100, it runs about 30 times faster than your implementation.

```
pos_1_start = 0

for i in range(np.size(vector1)):
    for j in range(pos1_start, np.size(vector2)):
        if np.abs(vector1[i] - vector2[j]) < .02:
            results1 += [(vector1[i], vector2[j], i, j)]
        else:
            if vector2[j] < vector1[i]:
                pos1_start += 1
            else:
                break
```

The timing:

```
time new method: 0.112464904785
time old method: 3.59720897675
```

Which is produced by the following script:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import time

# initialize the vectors to be compared
vector1 = [random.uniform(0, 40) for i in range(1000)]
vector2 = [random.uniform(0, 40) for i in range(1000)]

vector1.sort()
vector2.sort()

# the arrays that will contain the results for the first method
results1 = []

# the arrays that will contain the results for the second method
results2 = []

pos1_start = 0

t_start = time.time()
for i in range(np.size(vector1)):
    for j in range(pos1_start, np.size(vector2)):
        if np.abs(vector1[i] - vector2[j]) < .02:
            results1 += [(vector1[i], vector2[j], i, j)]
        else:
            if vector2[j] < vector1[i]:
                pos1_start += 1
            else:
                break

t1 = time.time() - t_start
print "time new method:", t1

t = time.time()
for lv1 in range(np.size(vector1)):
    for lv2 in range(np.size(vector2)):
        if np.abs(vector1[lv1]-vector2[lv2])<.02: 
            results2 += [(vector1[lv1], vector2[lv2], lv1, lv2)]
t2 = time.time() - t_start

print "time old method:", t2
# sort the results

results1.sort()
results2.sort()

print np.allclose(results1, results2)
```